# "attr(id) special check failed" jQuery

Tags: jquery

I receive this message from the console:

> attr(id) special check failed Insted of accessing the property via
>   attr(id), use undefined instead.

My code is really simple:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sezione = "";
    $('.menu_bar').click(function() {
        sezione = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

What could be the problem?

EDIT

This is the html in my page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/glamStyle2.css" />
<script src="http://www.modernizr.com/downloads/modernizr-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!--[if IE]><script src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script src="/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.1-all-min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/floating2.js"></script>
<title>Glam Group srl</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top_bar" class="menu_bar"></div>
    <div id="left_bar" class="menu_bar"></div>
    <div id="right_bar" class="menu_bar"></div>
    <div id="bottom_bar" class="menu_bar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I still don't understand the problem...

EDIT 2

This happen only within the firebug console in Firefox. I don't have this problem with the Chrome console.

Comment: Works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/zqTLu/ Give us more context please.

Comment: we need to see the html associated...

Comment: "special check failed"?  What's a "special check"?

Comment: if you just want the id try this.id, or this.getAttribute('id'), no need to use attr

Comment: This is not a message from jQuery itself, but from jQuery Lint: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-lint/

Comment: @jerjer this.getAttribute('id') works!
But i still having a lot of errors from jQuery Lint...
Something like
"jQuery(.menu_bar) special check failed"
or
"You've used the same selector more than once."
Am I doing this all wrong? Have i to disable lint from firebug?

This is the link of my demo:
[link](http://www.glamgroup.it/index2.php)

Comment: please check <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  the url isn't resolving.

Comment: thanks! I fixed the link. But the problem is still there...

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Lint is throwing the error.  It wants you to use `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')` since `this` already represents an [HTMLDivElement](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLDivElement.html) which has an `id` property.

From the jQuery Lint source:

```
langs = {
            en: {
                incorrectCall: '%0(%1) called incorrectly',
                specialCheckFailed: '%0(%1) special check failed',
                ...
                notBestMethod: 'Insted of accessing the property via %0(%1), use %2 insted', 
                ...
```

---

```
// check for non-ideal property/attribute access ( e.g. attr('id') - element.id is faster)
    each({'attr': {'id': 'elem.id', 'value': 'jQuery.val()'}}, function(method, attributes) {
        addCheck(method, 3, function() {
            if (typeof arguments !== 'undefined' && typeof attributes === 'object') {
                var match = false;
                for (m in arguments) {
                    if (attributes.hasOwnProperty(arguments[m])) {
                        match = arguments[m];
                    }
                }

                if (match !== false) {
                    var args = [].splice.call(arguments,0);
                    return lint.langs[lint.lang].notBestMethod.replace(/%0/, method)
                                                              .replace(/%1/, args.join(', '))
                                                              .replace(/%2/, attributes.match);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```